# Tensorflow session returns as 'closed'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have successfully ported the [CIFAR-10 ConvNet tutorial code](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html) for my own images and am able to train on my data and generate Tensorboard outputs etc.

My next step was to implement an evaluation of new data against the model I built. I am trying now to use **cifar10_eval.py** as a starting point however am running into some difficulty.

I should point out that the original tutorial code runs entirely without a problem, including **cifar10_eval.py**. However, when moving this particular code to my application, I get the following error message (last line).

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

I found this error is thrown by TF's session.py

```
# Check session.
if self._closed:
  raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
```

I have checked the directories in which all files should reside and be created, and all seems exactly as it should (they mirror perfectly those created by running the original tutorial code). They include a train, eval and data folders, containing checkpoints/events files, events file, and data binaries respectively.

I wonder if you could help pointing out how I can debug this, as I'm sure there may be something in the data flow that got disrupted when transitioning the code. Unfortunately, despite digging deep and comparing to the original, I can't find the source, as they are essentially similar with trivial changes in file names and destination directories only.

EDIT_01:
Debugging step by step, it seems the line that actually throws the error is #106 in the original **cifar10_eval.py**:

```
    def eval_once(args etc)
    ...    
      with tf.Session() as sess:
      ...   
        summary = tf.Summary()
        summary.ParseFromString(sess.run(summary_op))  # <========== line 106
```

`summary_op` is created in `def evaluate` of this same script and passed as an arg to `def eval_once`.

```
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
...
while True:
  eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, summary_op)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple (but humbling) error in indentation.

```
        summary = tf.Summary()
        summary.ParseFromString(sess.run(summary_op))
        summary.value.add(tag='Precision @ 1', simple_value=precision)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step)
```

was outside of the `try:` block, and of course, no session could be found.

Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) on Session, a session can be closed with `.close` command or when using it through a context-manager in `with` block.  I did `find tensorflow/models/image/cifar10 | xargs grep "sess"` and I don't see any `sess.close`, so it must be the later.

IE, you'll get this error if you do something like this

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(..)

sess.run(...)  # Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Comment: just added an edit that seems to pinpoint where the error arises--it seems you're on to something re `sess` but I still haven't figure out why the error keeps showing up

Comment: Should you be doing `less.run(summary_op)` instead of `sess.run(summary_op)`?